# Move a borderless window in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my C# WinForms app I have a main window that has its default controls hidden.

So to allow me to move it around I added the following to the main window:

```cs
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    if (message.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        message.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);

    //Allow window to move
    if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
        message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
}
```

I have a WPF App where I have also hidden the default controls and I want to do the same.  I see that the main window is derived from a 'Window' so the above code does not work.
How do I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 41):

To do this you will want to attach an event handler to the `MouseDown` event of the window, check that the left mouse button was pressed and call the `DragMove` method on the window.

Here is a sample of a window with this functionality:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseDown += Window_MouseDown;
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            DragMove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this causes my labels that are invoked via MouseUp or PreviewMouseUp to no longer get signaled.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I would try either using MouseUp for your labels if you can, or using buttons styled as labels and using the click event.

Comment: Can be minified as `protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e){if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) DragMove();}`

Answer (score 2):

It's super simple, here:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that user wants to drag the window. So left button of mouse should be down and it should be moving a least some pixels. Create a point property to store cursor's exact point and add two events to window itself: PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and MouseMove. Check the code below.

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Position = e.GetPosition(null);
}



private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = Position - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {
            DragMove();
        }
    }
```