# C# WPF move window elsewhere

Tags: c#, wpf, border, frame

[image]

[image]

I would love to move the application.
I've removed the frame for optical reasons, now I can not move the application as if I had a frame.
On picture 2 you see this frame, as soon as one goes to this frame and the Maustaste held can one move the application.
I would also like to do this with my application see picture 1.
How can I do that?
If I can move in my application this again?
For example, if I press on the white canvas so I can move it.

```
<Window x:Name="windowsForm" x:Class="Vorschau.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Vorschau"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="514.583" Width="805.208" FontFamily="Century Gothic" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" BorderThickness="0" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" Icon="C:\Users\benutzer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Vorschau\Vorschau\img\coordinates.ico">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Background="#FFE57E31">
        <Canvas Height="96" Canvas.Top="419" Width="185" Background="#FF2C373F">
            <Label x:Name="lbCopyright" Content="©  Name 2017" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="61" Width="121" Foreground="#FF1B1D1F"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Height="359" Canvas.Top="60" Width="185" Background="#FF37424A"/>
        <Canvas Height="60" Canvas.Left="185" Width="610">
            <Label x:Name="lbClose" Content="X" Canvas.Left="578" FontSize="20"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbMinimize" Content="-" Canvas.Left="556" FontSize="22" Canvas.Top="-2"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Height="455" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="60" Width="618" Background="#FFD1CFD0"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" Height="38" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="38" Source="C:\Users\benutzer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Vorschau\Vorschau\img\coordinates64.png"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbLogoname" Content="Vorschaukomponente" Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="10" Width="143" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623867/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to make your window movable.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseDown += Window_MouseDown;
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            DragMove();
    }
}
```

The code was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623867/1136211) with `MyWindow` replaced by `MainWindow`. Many thanks to user Phaeze.

Comment: See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the Help Center.

Comment: @Clemens ok let me check it