# Create button to move WPF window

Tags: wpf

I have a borderless WPF window that I am using this answer to move at the moment: [Move a borderless window in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623837/move-a-borderless-window-in-wpf)

But I would really like to have have a button that when you click and hold lets you drag the window around. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Should work just the same with a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just attach a `PreviewMouseDown` event to the Button and use similar code

XAML

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Move" />
```

or CodeBehind

```
Button button = new Button();
button.PreviewMouseDown += Move;
```

Code

```
private void Move(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // "window" is the name of the window
    window.DragMove();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```