# Move Borderless Window with a Panel

Tags: c#, .net

How to move an Borderless Window with Panel? I treid some Codes given in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623837/move-a-borderless-window-in-wpf) but none of them worked so i am asking how to do that. I only know how to move it without a Panel.

Comment: Get rid of the panel and your code will work.  Otherwise, you would have to apply the same code to the Panel's WndProc code.  Do that by inheriting from it.  Gets complicated and isn't user friendly as you think.

Comment: @LarsTech hm alright ty

Comment: The question you linked is related to WPF, while Panel suggests WinForms. Which is it? Tag your question specifying the UI platform.